# Azure CosmosDB Data Trigger not taking actual updates

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have created an Azure Function using CosmosDB Trigger template as per: [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-cosmos-db-triggered-function)

It's working fine, I can see updates flowing in from my Collection created in Cosmos DB.

[image]

Now the problem is, I want only those documents which are having actual updates. Currently If I update document using code it updates it's timestamp & document comes under update. Although there is no actual Data Update.

**My questions:**

1. How can I only get Actual Updated documents(only those documents whose json fields are modified)?
2. How can I also track deleted documents? they are not flowing here as well??

Comment: what do you mean by this: "if I update document using code"?

Comment: using azure java sdk to put data in cosmos collection

Comment: so you mean you only want to get updates but not newly created documents?!

Comment: i want newly created documents, updates & delete as well. Ultimately trying to achieve CDC.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you mean by `documents which are having actual updates`. It would help if you include an example of the same.

Comment: Even after you update I'm guessing: So you "update" a document but haven't changed the documents content?!

Comment: yes correct, when I am saying actual update, I am trying to update a document with exact same json which i pushed earlier.

Comment: see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Since any push to the document updates the - internally managed - `_ts` attribute, this still is a change to the overall document. If you changed the user data of the document does not matter here. The change feed does not know of this distinction. So you will always see those updates in the change feed as well.

2) Deletions are not added to the change feed but there is a possible workaround:

> Currently change feed doesn’t log deletes. [...] you can add a soft marker on the items that are being deleted, for example, you can add an attribute in the item called "deleted" and set it to "true" and set a TTL on the item, so that it can be automatically deleted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#change-feed-and-different-operations

Comment: I have implemented this soft marker, and fetching updates while indexing the same data in Azure Search. that works well. Now only challenge is I have millions of documents coming everyday is Cosmos. I only want to index the updated one in Azure Search. If I update a document with exact same json everyday(because it is flowing from upstream everyday) then I need to reindex all the documents in Azure Search as well. That was the reason I was trying to see Azure Functions. If they can help in solving this problem.

Comment: The Azure Function trigger for CosmosDB is based on the CosmosDB change feed. So it is bound by the same restrictions.

Comment: ok, so then I need to handle this in code itself before insert/update read the same document.